# is there a way of changing the accent of a region's header according to the value of an item?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to set the accent/backgroud-color of a regions's header according to the value of `:P4_COLOR` item. For example, if `:P4_COLOR = blue` so the accent of the actual regions's header must be blue (i.e., `u-color-1`).

I have tried to use html `backgroud-color` inside an `h1` tag, for example:

`<h1 style="background-color:&P4_COLOR.;">Title name</h1>`

but the result is not equal as the template option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following JavaScript would apply the same as the template option

```
$('#region_static_id').addClass('t-Region--accent1')
```

Or to use the color modifier

```
$('#region_static_id .t-Region-header').addClass('u-color-9-bg')
```

Or you could supply the accent as a substitution string in the Appearance-CSS classes in the region.

[image]